# glxCreateContextAttribsARB and dynamic loading of OpenGL funcs on linux

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glx

I need to dynamically load openGL functions on a linux system. The problem is that when I do that glXCreateContextAttribsARB fails when trying to create a gl context and the program falls back to using OGL 1.4. It should be on OGL 4.4. If I just use the shared library and do a regular linkage, the code works perfectly. So there is some issue with using the dynamically loaded lib that I'm not seeing. The functions are being loaded with dlopen/dlsym and no errors are being reported. I tried loading glXCreateContextAttribsARB using glxGetProcAddressARB , but it made no difference. I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Ubuntu 12.04LTS/GLX 1.4/OGL 4.4/Nvidia 331.62

Comment: Do you have Mesa library at the same moment? If so - you get clash between NVidia proprietary drivers and Mesa library.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. For some reason the code was trying to use an incompatible visual (24bit FB instead of 32bits). I made the attribute list for glxChooseVisual more precise in my requirements. Why this somehow worked with shared libs and not with dynamic libs is a mystery.